# Read X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read the value of the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header value in a request.

I've tried

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].Split(new char[] { ',' }).FirstOrDefault();
```

in C#.

OR do I need to split the header by `":"` and the take the second string?
I am asking this because, Wikipedia says

> The general format of the field is:
>   X-Forwarded-For: client1, proxy1, proxy2

Comment: you code is correct, except I'd do just this: HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].Split(',').FirstOrDefault();

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XFF

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The format that you get in return is **client1, proxy1, proxy2**

So you split it with the comma, and get the first to see the ip of your client.

Comment: THIS SUGGESTION IS DANGEROUS, in particular if used for access control. The originating client can also add an X-Forwarded-For header with his request, and then typically insert an internal IP address there. Google "X-Forwarded-For hack". You must work your way up backwards and assert that each address is a proxy that you control. When you encounter an IP address that you do not know, you use this as the client address. This way, if the hacker starts the list out with a IP address, possibly one that you recognize as internal to your network, you will not trust that.

Comment: @stolsvik I think that you must never use an ip for access control anyway. The ip is for statistics, and for check for bad behavior if this is possible.

Answer (score 12):

If helps, this is a simple way of getting the user's IP address, considering the X_FORWARDED_FOR header

```
var forwardedFor = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

var userIpAddress = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(forwardedFor) ?
    Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : forwardedFor.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 11):

Don't forget that X-Forwarded-For can contain whatever client writes there. It can contain XSS or SQL-injection inside.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the first may contain one of the local (private) reserved addresses which is not useful.  Also the first position(s) are open to to spoofing.

Update - April 2018:  Sampling the cases of a live production website where the first address is local (private) indicates some configuration issue on the end user's network or his ISP.  The cases are occurring only rarely (<1%) and consistently for the same end users.

The answer below suggests walking from right to left until you hit a public address.  Not sure anyone actually does this but it points out the issue.

https://husobee.github.io/golang/ip-address/2015/12/17/remote-ip-go.html