# How to restrict some IP in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ip-address

I have converted my website from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core.

In the original ASP.NET project, I had restricted some IPs via the webconfig like this:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
        <add ipAddress="92.127.176.55" />
        <add ipAddress="92.124.0.0" subnetMask="255.252.0.0" />
    </ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Is it possible to restrict IPs in the ASP.NET Core project in a similar way?

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP Security in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40427164/ip-security-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ZNetCS.AspNetCore.IPFiltering to block some ip address;
//install using command

```
PM> Install-Package ZNetCS.AspNetCore.IPFiltering
```

//In Startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
 services.AddIPFiltering(this.Configuration.GetSection("IPFiltering"));
```

// In Startup.cs Configure add

```
  app.UseIPFiltering();
```

// In appsetting.json add **IPFiltering**

```
"IPFiltering": {
    "DefaultBlockLevel": "All",
    "HttpStatusCode": 404,
    "Whitelist": [ "192.168.0.10-192.168.10.20", "fe80::/10" ],
    "Blacklist": [ "192.168.0.100-192.168.1.200"],
    "IgnoredPaths": [ "GET:/ignoreget", "*:/ignore" ]
}
```