# Internet enabled IIS Site always returning Local IP

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP .Net Core, the below code always returning 127.0.0.1 (The Local IP)when deployed in Internet enable site

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Tried the below code as well in Startup.cs but no use.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
              Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```

Looking forward for your solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core

Comment: How are you hosting the app? Kestrel behind IIS as reverse proxy?  You need to configure IIS to actually populate the X-Forwarded-For header.

Comment: @PranayRana did you really copy the question title into Google, copy the first line of code you saw and hurriedly typed a sentence full of typos, ignoring the code in this question?

Comment: @CodeCaster It's like the third time I see that from the same user today

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you please explain more about configuring the IIS to populate X-Forwarded-For