# Obtaining External IP with ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ip-address, f5

I am attempting to obtain similar information as found on [https://www.whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/). I specifically am looking for the external and local IP addresses. This is the .NET Core code that I am using to obtain this information:

**HomeController.cs**

```
ViewData["RemoteIp"] = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
ViewData["LocalIp"] = HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor
        });
```

The application lives behind an F5, so it results with a remote IP with my machine IP and a local IP that is the loopback IP address. The DNS entry is available externally, which then goes through the F5, then points to the server running the application.

Ideally, I would like the remote IP to return the external IP as done in the [ipify API](https://www.ipify.org/).

I've reviewed the following SO threads already in attempt for a solution: [How to get Client IP address in ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116403/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core-2-1)

I've also reviewed the MSDN documentation as found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1

One other factor: I plan on reusing this concept across multiple devices, including iOS, Android, and Windows platforms. I haven't decided on a framework, but I've entertained the ideas of Xamarin and PhoneGap.

Comment: Did you enable *Insert X-Forwarded-For* at the *HTTP Profile* associated to your *Virtual Server* ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? All the help I found relates to the full .NET framework

Comment: @AntLaC Yes, we found a solution to this. It was unrelated to the code. The code functions correctly. The actual issue was that the X-Forwarded IP address was transformed to point to a different IP address once it hit the server. Between our firewall and server, though, the X-Forwarded IP was correct. We had to reconfigure server settings to prevent the X-Forwarded IP to be transformed.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Yes, we did. See my previous comment regarding the actual issue. Thank you.