# The best way to get the client IP address in Azure durable function?

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

What is the correct way of obtaining the remote IP address (the address of the client making the request) in an Azure durable function?

**The beginning of my HttpStart method**

```cs
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "report-data/get")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
        {
```

I tried
`((HttpContext)req.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();` but the `MS_HttpContext` property is missing.

I also tried

```cs
        string result = string.Empty;

        if (req.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Forwarded-For", out IEnumerable<string> headerValues))
        {
            result = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return result;
```

which returns and empty string.

I have looked at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211824/get-remote-ip-address-in-azure-function), but it assumes the request is of type `HttpRequest`. In my case, it is `HttpRequestMessage`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088949/1908586) suggests that the `X-Forwarded-For` header must be enabled first.  But I don't know how to do this in my Azure Function App (or for my durable function).

I am developing my Azure functions locally, using VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trying, I have managed to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51245326/1908586) to my `Azure Durable Function`. I also found this information on how to use [dependency injection in Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) quite handy. The steps were as follows:

1. Add the following method to the project's `Startup` class in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }
```

2. Add the folowing `using` statement to `Startup.cs`:
   `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`
3. Add the following private member and constructor to my orchestrator class

```cs
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
        public GetReportActionsOrchestration(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }
```

4. Add the following function for getting the client IP address to my orchestrator class:

```cs
        private string GetClientIpAddress()
        {
            string ip = _accessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
            return (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip)) ? string.Empty : ip;
        }
```

5. Modify the durable orchestration code to be compatible with dependency injection by removing `static` modifier from the orchestration's `HttpStart` and `RunOrchestrator` functions.
6. Add `string remoteIpAddress = this.GetClientIpAddress();` to `HttpStart` function to get the client's IP address, which can then be passed to `RunOrchestrator` as a parameter.
7. Changes to the orchestrator class require

```cs
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
        using System;
```