# Get user-agent and ip in Blazor server-side app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a server-side app with Blazor and I want get the **ip** and **user-agent** with each page request, how can I achieve that? In a .NET Core app I just need to use this code in the controller:

```
var userAgent  = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()
```

But in Blazor I can't retrieve this data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### User agent:

You can get it via [JavaScript interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Follow this easy steps:

On your `_Host.cshtml` file:

```html
<script>
window.getUserAgent = () => {
    return navigator.userAgent;
};
</script>
```

To get user agent on any Blazor page:

```cs
var remoteUserAgent = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getUserAgent");
```

[image: running app]

Notice you don't need to send user agent on each request, you can send it with your first request, all other client-side communication will be through the same socket.

Comment: and for remote-ip address we can do these steps :
1- services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
2- in @code {}  var request = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
3- var remoteIp = request.Connection.RemoteIpAddress

Comment: try      services.AddControllers();

Comment: Since you can get the http context, you can always get the user agent from it too: `var userAgent = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];`

Comment: be careful doing the httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(); trick. When i did this then published to Azure I would get "OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token." error when I tried to authenticate using Azure AD. It worked fine when I tested locally, and this error only occurred when publishing to Azure. I spent 4 days diagnosing this to figure out this was the cause!!

Answer (score 0):

Also answered in: [How do I get client IP and browser info in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982444/how-do-i-get-client-ip-and-browser-info-in-blazor/76699094#76699094)

There's numerous examples of what to add to _Host.cshtml.cs to get an anti-forgery token. You can piggy-back that by adding to that code in _Host.cshtml as follows:

```
@{
    var initialTokenState = new InitialApplicationState
        {
            XsrfToken = Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken,
            Cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"]
        };
    // try X-Forwarded-For first
    HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out var forwardedFor);
    if (forwardedFor.Count > 0)
        initialTokenState.RemoteIp = forwardedFor[0];
    else
        initialTokenState.RemoteIp = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
}
```

This exists for the life of the circuit and there's no way the remote IP changes while a circuit exists.

This answer only solves the client IP address half of the question.