# How can i access IP address of the client in Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

How do i check the Ip Address of the connected Client in Blazor Server Side?
I have certain administrative pages that i only want to allow from certain IP address.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982444/how-do-i-get-client-ip-and-browser-info-in-blazor