# Get the IP address of the caller to API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `dotnet` `core` `ASP` 3.1 `MVC` server app. I expose an HTTP `GET` through the `controllers`. Is there a way to get the `IP address` of the caller to the API?

Comment: See this : http://bekenty.com/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get client IP address in ASP.NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

you can use IHttpContextAccessor to get the IP. use this code in your controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public YourController (IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        var ip= accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
    }
}
```

and at the Startup.cs add this line of code to your ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: When hosting outside of IIS you may need to add Forwarded headers too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and `KnownProxies` may be necessary if more than 1 (reverse) proxy is used. Otherwise (if you cant use know networks) look into `ForwardLimit ` to control the forwarded for headers (which also includes remote IP in reverse proxy scenarios)

Comment: To access HttpContext in Controller, injecting HttpContextAccessor is not required. ControllerBase already contains HttpContext.

Comment: yes, of course there is httpcontext in controller base, But I suggest this if he wanted use in other class, he does it easily... @Bob