# How to get the client IP address when visiting my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use dotnet core 3.1 and I need the IP address of my website visitors, but when I try to get it, the IP of the server is returned, not the client. Here is the code I use:

```
var ip = _accessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

This returns null. Then I tried to get my IP address using a third-party website. So I did this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.ipify.org/");
```

This will also return the IP address of the server, not the client. Then I tried this:

```
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        return ip.ToString();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
string localIP = string.Empty;
using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
{
    socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
    IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
    localIP = endPoint.Address.ToString();
}
```

but they return local IP addresses.
return localIP.ToString();

And some codes line `HTTPContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` or `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` are not valid in dotnet core.
Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get client IP address in ASP.NET CORE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core) (Check all answers, not only the accepted one)

Comment: I use this: `string ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();`

Comment: @StephanBauer This returns null; I did config my startup.cs file, but in vain.

Comment: @Catalin This returns null as well, dear friend.

Comment: just try to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides NuGet package and use it according to this document: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/get-ip-address-in-asp-net-core-guidelines/  .  I hop it help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are running the website not by directly exposing `Kesterl` to the end clients but under some reverse proxy (IIS/nginx). In that case for `Connection.RemoteIpAddress` to work property you have to configure the application by adding something like following code in the startup:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor })
```