# How to get the client's IP automatically in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, ip, client

I want to find the user's IP without the user automatically submitting the request from the URL itself. When I do this locally, it returns the correct IP address, but when I publish the web service on the server, this IP becomes the server IP, what should I do?

For example, I have a service at the address **https://test.com/api/GetAddress**, I call this service in **PostMan** with the below code and it returns the user's IP address correctly, but when this service is on a site at the address **https://sitetest.com/Dashboard/GetHome** is called, the server address is returned and the user address is not given to me.

> Note that I want to get this IP through the URL itself, because if I
> put this in the Request and it is received through the developer, it
> can give any IP to the Api.

**I have used both types of code but still the same:**

```
public static string GetClientIp()
    {
        try
        {
            string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            return ipAddress?.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "10.0.0.0";
        }
        
        //return HttpContext.Current.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString() ?? "10.0.0.0";
    }
```

Comment: `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()` tries to get the host name of the server where the code is running. a little research on internet suggest to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core) and [this](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/get-ip-address-in-asp-net-core-guidelines/)

Comment: If you pay attention to the commented code, I have done these researches and I don't want to ask questions again. I have tried all the ways written in these articles and this happens again. @Chetan

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you try using any of the suggested approach on those link? How they are not solving your issue?

Comment: Is there a reverse proxy or load balancer before the server?

Comment: When I call the desired service directly in PostMan, it registers my IP correctly, but when this service is called through a site, the IP address of the server is given to me.  @4L4M1N

Comment: Who is calling `GetClientIp` method in the code? Who is client and server here? Can you provide bit more information of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Tolulope **no**

Answer (score 2):

Inside a controller get the client ip address using:

```
var address = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

If you are using a reverse proxy then you have to use the Forwarded Headers Middleware. Example:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

This is because the proxy forwards the request to your app so RemoteIpAdress has the ip address of the machine where the proxy is running. Most proxies usually set X-Forwarded-For header with the originating ip address. This middleware reads X-Forwarded-For header and sets the RemoteIpAdress correctly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: I have done this but it did not work

Comment: Do you understand the example I wrote?

Comment: So are you using a reverse proxy or not? If yes, which one?

Comment: My question is, can this method be executed automatically on the web service side without getting the address in the controller client or not?

Comment: What does 'automatically' mean? A client has to make an http request to server. The http context of the request contain information like the ip address of the client which sent the request.

Comment: Your `GetClientIp` method returns the ip address of the machine where the app is running.

Comment: yes, Finally, I think you understood because I really didn't know how to explain it anymore

Comment: No I did not understand. Your `GetClientIp` is wrong. It will always return the server ip address. What I'm showing you is how to get the client's ip address and for that you have to use the request http context. If you don't understand I don't know how else to explain.

Comment: Can you explain `it did not work`? What is it supposed to return and what is it returning instead for you(