In ASP.NET Core 8 MVC / C# project, I want to redirect the visitor to index or index2 according to the site he came from
If the visitor comes to my site from x.com, I want him to go to the index1 page, if he comes from other sites or directly, he should be directed to the index page, I tried a few examples and I could not succeed.
public IActionResult Index(string source)
{
    if (source == "orneksite1")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
    }

    return View();
}

The code redirects the visitor from x.com directly to the index.

Please describe in detail what you mean by "I could not succeed": errors? results of trying what? As it stands there is not enough information here to help you.

You have a controller with a HTTP connection.  You need to get the remote endpoint of the connection.  Try : ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core

Firstly, if we don't set any parameters or tags or some other configurations to tell the differences about the incoming request, we are not able to identify where the visitor comes from. Maybe we can ask the developer of x.com to add a specific parameter in the url to represent that this request is coming from x.com, or add a Referer request header and set the value as x.com which having the same effect. Then in our  code, just validate the url parameter or the request header.

Let's see a demo here.
public IActionResult Index(string? source)
{
    if (source == "privacy")
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
    var referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    if (referer == "privacy")
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
    return View();
}

When we open the browser and visit url https://localhost:7051/, it will return the Home view as it doesn't contain a parameter in the url. But if we visit https://localhost:7051/home/index?source=privacy, it will redirect to Privacy view. If we use tools to send a get request but add a Referer request header, it will redirect to Privacy view too.

Then you shall make an appointment with the development team of x.com to add request header Referer: x.com, so that you could use code like below to validate the incoming requests. This is just a demo, and it might require extra authentication/authorization to make sure it's a legal request.
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    if (referer != null && referer == "x.com")
        return RedirectToAction("Privacy");
    return View();
}

If we are not able to ask to change the source code of x.com, we might only use the remote ip address mentioned by @jdweng, but you have to sycn your validation code whenever x.com changed their host. Otherwise, your attempt for redirection might not work.
