# Azure Website Logs Including Internal IPs in Entries

Tags: azure, iis, logging, azure-web-app-service

For the last couple of weeks, we have been seeing an increasing amount of entries in the web logs of our Azure website whose originating IP address (in the c-ip column of the log) appears to be in the range 100.90.X.X. It has now reached more than half of all the traffic being logged, and is interfering with our ability to perform analytics and threat detection.

According to [the Wikipedia entry on reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), this block is part of one "Used for communications between a service provider and its subscribers when using a Carrier-grade NAT, as specified by RFC 6598", so **could this be a problem in Azure**?

Looking at the logs, the traffic comes from many different user agents (both normal users and the common legitimate bots) and is requesting a broad range of resources, so does not immediately appear suspicious other than the IPs. It looks more like legitimate traffic is being given an incorrect (internal) IP.

It seems to be only affecting static content (e.g. images and XML files), but not ALL static content.

We are using a single Small Standard instance in Western Europe, with a single web app running on it. We are not using any scaling features. There is a linked SQL database, and the website runs primarily over HTTPs. 95%+ of our traffic comes from UK sources. We have not made any changes to logging, which is handled by Azure.

**Is there any way that we can return to seeing the actual IPs here, or is this malicious traffic?**

Comment: could not find any other possible solution peter..i have deleted the same.

Comment: Thank you. The question can be distilled as "Azure is reporting internal routing IPs for static resources but the correct external IPs for dynamically served content, is this expected and can it be changed to record external IPs for ALL content?" - if you can provide any insight it would be much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: will try to get you soon

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible to alter the logging, but not on an app. The app diagnostic setting is pretty rudimentary — just a switch “to log or not to log?”

What you’ll be interested in is [this comparison](http://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2012/06/09/windows-azure-web-sites-vs-web-roles/) between apps (it was called “sites” then), roles (available through Cloud Service)<sup>1</sup> and virtual machines. The article mentions that there is more control over logging in the roles environment, which I would assume means that you can set up custom logs. [This article](https://techlib.barracuda.com/waf/iisserverclientiplog) details how to set up logging for the headers you choose in IIS. Now, you can fiddle with your IIS in a virtual machine, but there is a chance a cut-down version of this would work in a web role, for example. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn482131.aspx) discusses how to enable diagnostics logging in your cloud service hosted application.

Moving to cloud service from app environment is not trivial, since you have many more things you must set up. Possibly you’re looking at changing your solution’s structure, maybe altering the architecture of your app. So I wouldn’t consider doing it just so I could see a client’s IP.

The simplest thing you can do is try attaching analytics. [There used to be a solution straight from Azure](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Adding-Analytics-to-Azure-Web-Sites), but I can't find it in the portal. Google analytics is my go-to solution for traffic analysis. It may get you the information you want.

---

1. It’s really annoying how Microsoft rebrands an azure service every few months.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - yes ideally we would not want to move to a VM etc, the app has been running for two years happily as an App/Website, and we like the simplicity of the environment for scaling, continuous deployment etc. We use Google Analytics already, but also do custom log analysis for threat detection rather than the sort of analysis that you get in GA.

Comment: This question right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316796/x-forwarded-for shows a way to get the information you seek from the request header. So you can try to generate the relevant log right inside your application. `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].Split(new char[] { ',' })`

Comment: Thanks @Nomenator, but it only happens for static content (not served through ASP.NET). To do this, I would need to change the config so that the pipeline intercepts all traffic, which adds overhead just to log static files, and also I would still not have this in the standard IIS logs.

Comment: @Peter There’s yet another way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx so if you’re `using System.Web`, you can do it from inside any controller’s action: `string ip = Request.ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"];` If you’re already putting out logs and have a logger class (I know I’m doing logs inside my application), then it is not so difficult to add another log and not break SOLID.