# How to disable Google proxy used for Chrome's mobile data compression in C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cookies, proxy

When a user want to login to my website (C#, MVC), I save the IP address by code below in a cookie:

```
   HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

After user redirected to account when I want to get the IP address again and compare it with saved IP on cookie , IP has been changed to : " 66.249.93.88"

after some researches I found that this is because of Google proxy used for Chrome's mobile data compression and when I disable it on the setting everything work fine.

Now I want to know is that a way to disable data compression by codes or... to preventing IP changing?

Is there a way to find main IP address after changing to proxy IP?

I don't want my users change their Chrome's mobile setting.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression#faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JoshLee for this link:

[Read X-Forwarded-For header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316796/read-x-forwarded-for-header)

and:

```
As a site owner, how do I perform IP geo-targeting?
The IP address of your device is forwarded to the destination server via the 
X-Forwarded-For header. Site owners should check for this header to 
correctly determine the location of the user based on client's IP
```

This function can help you to get the currect IP address:

```
public static string GetRequestIp()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"] != null)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].Split(new char[] { ',' })[0].ToString();
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    }
```