# Cant Get the IP Address Of the client On my Published Website

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, ip-address, infrastructure

I have implemented a simple API that returns the ip address of the client "Request Sender". When I'm outside the network it always returns the same ip address when inside the network it works perfectly fine and it returns the local ip address of the device. 
The website is hosted on IIS the api logic is the following:

```
public static class iphelper
    {
        private const string HttpContext = "MS_HttpContext";
        private const string RemoteEndpointMessage = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.RemoteEndpointMessageProperty";

        public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpContext))
            {
                dynamic ctx = request.Properties[HttpContext];
                if (ctx != null)
                {
                    return ctx.Request.UserHostAddress;
                }
            }

            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessage))
            {
                dynamic remoteEndpoint = request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessage];
                if (remoteEndpoint != null)
                {
                    return remoteEndpoint.Address;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried ALL of the Snippets out there all returns the same. My project uses ASP.NET MVC C#.

i tried HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR always return null

Comment: Why you don't use `System.Web.HttpContext`  directly ?  you can get it from your controller right ?

Comment: I think it's a question about how networks work, not about asp.net or even programming. What do you mean by " it always returns the same ip address"? Could you describe some cases: what do you think it should return and what it's actually returning?

Comment: What web server are you using? Is it behind some kind of load balancer or network device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read X-Forwarded-For header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316796/read-x-forwarded-for-header)

Comment: @mjwills maybe im not sure but when i try X-Forwarded-For 
always return null its never returns a value

Comment: i tried that the X-Forwarded-For returns null all the time 

and the REMOTE_ADDR reruns  192.168.130.140

Comment: public string GetIPAddress()
        {

            return iphelper.GetClientIpAddress(Request);

        }

i actually dont know if there a load balancer im developing via vpn i dont have direct access to the network

Comment: You need to speak to your Operations team and ask them what machine is running at `192.168.130.140`.

Comment: i made a work around for it but i dont like it vary much that is i call and third party Web-service that Returns The ip addres of the Request sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is related to a load balancer or network device **in front of** your web server.

Given that:

> REMOTE_ADDR reruns 192.168.130.140

I would suggest asking your Operations team what machine is running at that IP, and how it could pass through the calling IP Address (likely through `X-Forwarded-For`).